# Ansible refer top level dict as variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a simple dict that has all details about domains. I am able to extract the details if I pass the second level as a variable for example

```
domain_details:
  domain_1:
    port: 8001
    primary_machine: host_1
    secondary_machine: host_2
    domain_user: example_user
    domain_group: example_group
  domain_2:
    port: 8010
    primary_machine: host_3
    secondary_machine: host_4
    domain_user: example_user
    domain_group: example_group
```

My playbook to call

```
- hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: false
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: | 
          {{ domain_details[domain_name] | type_debug }}
          {{ domain_details[domain_name] }}
```

Call the playbook as

```
ansible-playbook sample.yml -f 1 -e domain_name=domain_1
```

And the output is good with no errors.

```
MSG:

dict
{'admin_server_listen_port': 8001, 'primary_machine': 'host_1', 'secondary_machine': 'host_2', 'domain_owner': 'example_user', 'domain_group': 'example_user'}
```

If I change my dict and remove the top level I am unable to refer to that as a variable.

```
domain_1:
  port: 8001
  primary_machine: host_1
  secondary_machine: host_2
  domain_user: example_user
  domain_group: example_group
domain_2:
  port: 8010
  primary_machine: host_3
  secondary_machine: host_4
  domain_user: example_user
  domain_group: example_group
```

Change my playbook as below and call the earlier

```
- hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: false
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: | 
          {{ [domain_name] | type_debug }}
          {{ [domain_name] }}
```

and the o/p is only displaying the list name not the values, how to get that.

```
MSG:

list
['domain_1']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the lookup plugin *vars* to indirectly reference a variable. Declare the variable below

```yaml
  result: "{{ lookup('vars', domain_name) }}"
```

If you set the extra variable `-e domain_name=domain_1` this gives

```yaml
  result:
    domain_group: example_group
    domain_user: example_user
    port: 8001
    primary_machine: host_1
    secondary_machine: host_2
```

See details

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    domain_1:
      port: 8001
      primary_machine: host_1
      secondary_machine: host_2
      domain_user: example_user
      domain_group: example_group
    domain_2:
      port: 8010
      primary_machine: host_3
      secondary_machine: host_4
      domain_user: example_user
      domain_group: example_group

    result: "{{ lookup('vars', domain_name) }}"
      
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e domain_name=domain_1

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
    domain_group: example_group
    domain_user: example_user
    port: 8001
    primary_machine: host_1
    secondary_machine: host_2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"How I can assign these to facts?"***

A: Use *set_fact* to 'instantiate' a variable

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ result }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolves part of the problem, How I can assign these to facts? I want to refer `port`  and other variables. Right now I am using like below 

```- name:  Setting domain facts
  set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ domain_details[domain_name] | dict2items }}" ``` - is there any way ?

Comment: Use *set_fact*.

Comment: that will set all values in the results. however, if I do like earlier it will assign the fact as port and value as 8001 for domain_1. 

```ok: [localhost] => {
    "result1": {
        "domain_group": "example_group",
        "domain_user": "example_user",
        "port": 8001,
        "primary_machine": "host_1",
        "secondary_machine": "host_2"
    }
}```

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. There is no *result1* either in your or mine code. Open a new question and make it [mre]. Reduce the data to minimum {k1: v1, k2: v2, ...}. Avoid live examples if possible, please.

Comment: I just referred the results variable as result1, for my convenience. changed back now.  by using your way results will contain all values including `port`. i was looking for each value, but I got that using 'result.port` and other variable i can get with `result.`
playbook
```  - debug: var=result
   - debug: var=result.port```

like this
```ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.port": "8001"
}```